# WP_Query Events - How can I display event dates even if no event scheduled for that day

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a Tribe Event Calendar custom Carousel query (wP_Query) in Wordpress using a custom query. I have the events query working great, but I want to display even the empty dates that have no events scheduled. Is that possible or is there a workaround? Any help would be appreciated!

My Query Code:

```
$args = array(
   'post_status'=>'publish',
   'post_type'=>array(TribeEvents::POSTTYPE),
   'posts_per_page'=>10,
   'start_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-1 week' ) ),
   'end_date'       => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '+1 month' ) ),
   //order by startdate from newest to oldest
   'meta_key'=>'_EventStartDate',
   'orderby'=>'_EventStartDate',
   'order'=>'ASC',
   //required in 3.x
   'eventDisplay'=>'custom', 
);

$get_posts = null;
$get_posts = new WP_Query();
$get_posts->query($args);

if($get_posts->have_posts()) {
   while($get_posts->have_posts()) : $get_posts->the_post();  

  // display results here from loop

  endwhile;
}

wp_reset_query();
```

UPDATE:
I found this script that may work. Then I can mess with the format of the date. I believe I was just overthinking the actual issue. I will provide a working code once I get get this figured out.

```
$start_date = '2012-01-01'; /* I can change this to strtotime( '-1 week' ) */
$end_date = '2012-12-31'; /* and this to strtotime( '+1 month' ) but mess with the format in PHP Y-m-d */

$start    = new DateTime($start_date);
$end      = new DateTime($end_date);
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 day interval
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $day) {
    // Do stuff with each $day...
    echo $day->format('Y-m-d'), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Do these events that you want to add have a `_EventStartDate` custom field which is empty, or do they not have the field at all?

Comment: They don't have a field at all. Just want to have the empty inbetween dates sort of like a regular calendar. Then I can add "Nothing Scheduled for this date" to each

Comment: You could try with the `relation => OR` and a `NOT EXISTS` in a custom meta query array. But since they don't *have* that field, how do you want to order them?

Comment: I would just want them ordered by date earliest to later. Not sure how to write that since `_EventStartDate` doesn't have a value. Would I just leave the value out if i nested the meta_query?

Comment: I had a similar issue recently and I had to do a workaround with 2 queries. If I remember correctly, sort order did not work when some of the items did not have the meta key that was used for sorting.

Comment: Yea I believe what I need is to run a query inside a query. So first, I need to query an array of dates that don't have posts tied to them, then for each date inside the loop, run a second query to check if there is an event post for that day. I am just not sure how to do a query that returns a range of dates (Example: Oct. 7th, 8th, 9th, ..... 24th) . Those dates would simply be the actual date and display (Oct 7th) just like a calendar would. Then the query inside can just display the event only if there is one. If not, "There are no events for this day". Do you know where I can find script?